# Logical systems where both the order and multiplicity of premises matter

Tags: logic, reference-request

In most logical systems, the order and multiplicity of premises do not matter. For example, the set $\{A,A\}$ has the same logical consequences as the set $\{A\}$, and the set $\{A,B\}$ has the same logical consequences as the set $\{B,A\}$. However, has anyone defined and studied a logical system where the order and multiplicity of premises matter? For example, consider a binary connective $f$. There is a rule that states that from the sequence $(A,B)$, we can infer $f(A,B)$, but we cannot always infer $f(A,B)$ from the sequence $(B,A)$. Also, we cannot always infer $f(A,A)$ from the sequence $(A)$, but we can infer it from the sequence $(A,A)$. That is just one example of a connective that depends on both order and multiplicity of premises. Anyway, has logical systems like that been studied in the mathematical literature?

Comment: I'm not personally aware of any logics whose sequents are "noncommutative", but you might be interested in [linear logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-linear/), which makes a marked distinction between the assumptions $A$ and $(A,A)$ (since assumptions are "consumed" after a single use). In general, a keyword you might want to google is [substructural logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_logic), which is a catchall term for logics where we go without some of the "structural" axioms, like exchange, weakening, and contraction (which are of particular interest to you).

Comment: There exists "cyclic linear logic" which pays attention to the multiplicity of premises (as @HallaSurvivor described) and also pays a certain limited attention to the order of premises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like "noncommutative logic" really was the right keyword to google. These are [substructural logics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substructural_logic) where we miss out the [structural axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#An_intuitive_explanation)

- Weakening, which says we can add ~bonus assumptions~:

$$\frac{\Gamma \vdash \varphi}{\Gamma, A \vdash \varphi}$$

- Contraction, which says we can ignore duplicate assumptions:

$$\frac{\Gamma, A, A \vdash \varphi}{\Gamma, A \vdash \varphi}$$

- Exchange, which says we can permute our assumptions freely:

$$\frac{\Gamma_1, A, B, \Gamma_2 \vdash \varphi}{\Gamma_1, B, A, \Gamma_2 \vdash \varphi}$$

Following Andreas's comment, you can find "cyclic linear logic" discussed on the wikipedia page for [noncommutative logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_logic). You can also find a nice paper about cyclic linear logic [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/abs/quantales-and-noncommutative-linear-logic/1808CA04372612BCB38E8D3A8B4CCCDB).

Additionally, [here](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Efp/courses/15816-s98/handouts/notes.pdf) is a set of notes about linear logic, with applications to programming language theory. Chapter $6$ in particular is about noncommutative linear logic, and this set of notes also has a nice bibliography where you can find more.

---

I hope this helps ^_^